# How do I issue a quit message with perl's POE::Component::IRC?

Tags: perl, irc

I have a simple IRC bot using POE::Component::IRC. It was only when I was attempting to make it gracefully handle SIGINT by quitting with a useful message that I found that I can't make it quit with any message at all, ever whether as part of a signal handler or just a normal call to quit.

Let's say I've got the session created something like this:

```
POE::Session->create(
        inline_states => {
                irc_disconnected => \&bot_reconnect,
                irc_error        => \&bot_reconnect,
                irc_socketerr    => \&bot_reconnect,
                connect          => \&bot_reconnect,
.
.
.
        },
);
```

And `bot_reconnect` is just going to connect back to IRC should
anything go wrong:

```
sub bot_reconnect
{
        my ($kernel, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP];

        if (1 == $heap->{shutting_down}) {
                $heap->{irc}->yield(shutdown => 'blah');
        } else {
                some_log_func("Reconnecting in 60 secs");
                $kernel-delay(connect => 60);
        }
}
```

If, anywhere else in the code I set `shutting_down` to 1 and tell it
to quit (e.g.  `$irc->yield(quit => "bye!")`) it immediately quits
IRC with either no quit message ("Client Quit", the ircd displays)
or else with "Remote host closed the connection".

It then receives the `irc_disconnected` event which takes it to
`bot_reconnect` above, where `shutdown` appears to do nothing at
all. In fact if I don't explicitly `exit 0` after that `shutdown`
then the process just stays in limbo with no connect to IRC any
more.

Is that what is supposed to happen?

I found:

http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/POE-Component-IRC-6.79/lib/POE/Component/IRC/Cookbook/Disconnecting.pod

which says to use `shutdown`. As you can see, I tried that, and it
doesn't seem to work.

I also found some sample code for this in another question:

[How do I correctly shutdown a Bot::BasicBot bot (based on POE::Component::IRC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471373/how-do-i-correctly-shutdown-a-botbasicbot-bot-based-on-poecomponentirc)

However that is very similar to what I have now, and it also doesn't
seem to behave any differently.

The package version of `libpoe-component-irc-perl` is 6.78+dfsg-1 so
that should be greater than 6.50 as the above URL says.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is the "fault" of the ircd.

I also reported this as a bug to POE::Component::IRC's request tracker, and Hinrik responded, asking me if I was trying to do this on Freenode. Freenode's ircd has a feature where it ignores your quit message if you haven't been connected for very long.

I wasn't trying to do it on Freenode, but it turns out that the network I was doing it on *does* do this. They're using Charybdis:

https://github.com/atheme/charybdis/blob/master/modules/core/m_quit.c#L75

Comment: This is common to all many ircds (certainly in the ircd-hybrid lineage).  Before this was implemented, spammers realised that they could have a bot connect, quickly join the maximum number of channels, then quit with a spam quit message which would be broadcast to everyone in all those channels.